# Data is not displaying in jsp page using for each loop

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am newbie in Spring mvc. Currently I am trying to create a web page to perform view and create of Employee Object using spring mvc. But in my web page view of employee is not displaying,

My Controller is as follow

```
package com.testapp.springmvc.controllers;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.testapp.springmvc..models.Employee;

@Controller
public class TestController {
    HashMap<Integer, Employee> employees = new HashMap<>();
    Integer count = 0;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String employee(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
        model.addAttribute("listOfEmployee", employees.values());
        return "employee";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee) {
        employees.put(++count, employee);
        return "redirect:employee";
    }
}
```

My jsp view is follow

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form action="employee" commandName="employee" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:input path="id" disable="true" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name of Employee <br> <form:input type="text"
                        path="fname" name="fname" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Surname of Employee <br> <form:input path="lname"
                        type="text" name="lname" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Add Employee" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
    <c:if test="${!empty listOfEmployee}">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${listOfEmployee}" var="employee">
                <tr>
                    <td>${employee.fname}</td>
                    <td>${employee.lname}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </c:if>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which method are you calling from controller?

Comment: when jsp is loaded employee() method is invoked, when we click on submit button at that time addEmployee() is called.

Comment: why you're putting this model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee()); since you're declaring a hashMap of employee object

Comment: @PacMan If we not put employee in model attribute then it will threw exception "exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'employee' available as request attribute] with root cause"

Comment: did you implement any business logic level in your project , i mean a class having as method getAllEmployees() !!

Comment: @PacMan Nope I haven't implement any business logic. I am just trying to store employee object in a hashmap and displaying them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is not working because in my web.xml file I am using 2.3 dtd, after upgrading dtd definition to 3.1 code is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

so the hashMap will never be fulled with Employees Object which is normal since you're not implementing a business logic !! try to create Employees object in the controller (even it is not recommended) and add them to the hashMap and then when you load the page "/employee" by default with a `GET` method it will list you the Employess you've been fullfilled in your hashMap.

Comment: I am adding employee object into the hashmap in addEmployee() method.

Comment: in your form try to add as attribute modelAttribute="employee"